# Bind WinUI 3 ContentDialog DataContext to Property

Tags: c#, winui-3

I am using a custom `ContentDialog` in a WinUI 3 application to get information from the user. I want to use a property in the content dialog as its data source, but I can't work it out.

Here's a trimmed down version of the dialog's markup:

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="Question.CustomContentDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Question"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{Binding OurModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource.Self}}"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    PrimaryButtonText="OK">

    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```

And the code for the dialog and data classes:

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Question
{
    public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        private string _name = string.Empty;

        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Name)));
            }
        }
    }

    public sealed partial class CustomContentDialog : ContentDialog
    {
        public Model OurModel { get; set; } = new() { Name = "Foo" };

        public CustomContentDialog()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

The dialog class is used like this:

```
{
    var dialog = new CustomContentDialog
    {
        Title = "This is a test",
        XamlRoot = Content.XamlRoot,
    };
    dialog.OurModel.Name = "Test";
    var _ = dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

My expectation would be that the attribute, `d:DataContext="{Binding OurModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource.Self}}"` would set the `DataContext` of the `ContentDialog` to the `OurModel` property of the object itself -- and Intellisense in the Xaml file seems to bear that out -- but no binding is actually created. If it were, the text box would be set to either "Test" or "Foo", and the value of `dialog.OurModel` would reflect the user's changes when `dialog.ShowAsync()` returned, wouldn't it? That's what I'm hoping to accomplish.

I managed to work around this by creating a binding in the xaml file

```
<ContentDialog.DataContext>
    <models:Model x:Name="TheModel"/>
</ContentDialog.DataContext>
```

but that creates a private property, `TheModel` in the class, which can't be set externally without a lot of extra rigmarole.

Comment: Just put `DataContext = OurModel;` in `CustomContentDialog` constructor after `this.InitializeComponent`.

Comment: That's easy enough, but I have to wonder why the `DataContext` can't be set in the markup.

Comment: It wasn't clear what you wanted is to do everything in XAML. For pure XAML use this: `<TextBox Text="{x:Bind OurModel.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />` . `x:Bind` is more powerful than `Binding` which is kinda deprecated https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/function-bindings

Comment: Oh, your answer was perfect. I was trying to get my solution to work instead of solving the problem. I can live with the mystery.

Comment: @padeso Is your problem solved then? Would you like to create an answer and mark it as solution so others can see better what solved your issue?