# C# WinUI 3 Bind ContentDialog

Tags: c#, binding, desktop, winui-3, contentdialog

I have a ContentDialog triggered when a user clicks on a row in a DataGrid. The primary goal of the ContentDialog is to allow the user to enter and save a comment via a textbox control named 'Cmnt_Apprvl_Mgmt' in the ContentDialog. The logic is working now.

Now I would like some of the data from the clicked row from the DataGrid to appear in the ContentDialog.  I have not been able to figure out how to do it.

I pass 'rowModel' (data from the datagrid) as a parameter to the new contentdialog (v3).
I would like any previous comment already entered for a particular row to populate the textbox 'Cmnt_Apprvl_Mgmt' in the ContentDialog.

Thank you in advance StackOverflow-contributors, you have been so helpful to me during this project. It is greatly appreciated.

My code: (xaml)

```
<ContentDialog x:Name="MgmtApprovalDialog"
               Title = "Enter Management Approval Comment"
               PrimaryButtonText="Save"
               CloseButtonText="Cancel"
               Opened="MgmtApprovalDialog_Opened"
               PrimaryButtonClick="MgmtApprovalDialog_PrimaryButtonClick">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="Cmnt_Apprvl_Mgmt" PlaceholderText="Enter Comment" Margin="0 0 0 0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="80" TextChanged="Cmnt_Apprvl_Mgmt_TextChanged"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="errorTextBlock" Margin="0 10 0 5" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Oblique"/>
        <!-- Content body -->
        <TextBlock Name="body" TextWrapping="Wrap">
            <TextBlock.Text>
                When a target is not met, a comment from management is required (long and detailed)                       
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</ContentDialog>

C#

private void MgmtApprovalDialog_PrimaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
{
            // Ensure the comment field is empty. If a required field
            // is empty, set args.Cancel = true to keep the dialog open.
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Cmnt_Apprvl_Mgmt.Text))
            {
                args.Cancel = true;
                errorTextBlock.Text = "Comment is required.";
            }
}
            
private void DataGrid_Detail_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                DataGridRow clickedRow = FindParent<DataGridRow>((UIElement)e.OriginalSource);
                if (clickedRow != null)
                {
                    Approvals rowModel = (Approvals)clickedRow.DataContext;
                    // Do stuff
                    // DisplayCommentDialog();
                    //DisplayCommentDialog_v2(rowModel);
                    DisplayCommentDialog_v3(rowModel);
                }
            }

        // +---------------------------------------------------------
        // | DISPLAY COMMENT DIALOG V3
        // +---------------------------------------------------------
        private async void DisplayCommentDialog_v3(Approvals rowModel)
        {
            ContentDialogResult result = await MgmtApprovalDialog.ShowAsync();
            if (result == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
            {
                // Save button clicked
                Debug.WriteLine($"+-------------------------------------------------------------------");
                Debug.WriteLine($"| Hello - inside DisplayCommentDialog_v3 Primary Button Clicked!");
                Debug.WriteLine($"| Hello - Comment ID  : {rowModel.Comment_ID}");
                Debug.WriteLine($"| Hello - Comment Text: {Cmnt_Apprvl_Mgmt.Text}");
                Debug.WriteLine($"+-------------------------------------------------------------------");
                SaveMgMtApprovalComment(rowModel.Comment_ID, Cmnt_Apprvl_Mgmt.Text);
                // Before refreshing the DataGrid_Detail you must re-pull from the server (this may be a design flaw.)
                GetSQLData_Approvals();
                // Refresh DataGrid_Detail so the user can see what was just entered
                PopulateApprovalDetDG(v_product);
            }
            else
            {
                // User pressed Cancel, ESC, or the back arrow.
                // Terms of use were not accepted.
                Debug.WriteLine($"+-------------------------------------------------------------------");
                Debug.WriteLine($"| Hello - inside DisplayCommentDialog_v3 (Cancel, ESC, or back arrow)");
                Debug.WriteLine($"+-------------------------------------------------------------------");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Binding, Binding, Binding. WinUI3 (like all XAMLs techs) is totally unusable w/o abusing data binding. Just set MgmtApprovalDialog.DataContext to rowModel and bind MgmtApprovalDialog to rowmodel's properties. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75149524/bind-winui-3-contentdialog-datacontext-to-property

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply Simon Mourier!  I had seen your other post, and I tried to implement it but could not make it work.Then I posted my question. I am still a C# newbie.  I will be studying your other post so I can understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1: DataContext and Bindings

An easy solution is the one proposed by Simon Mourier in his comment.

Simply set the `DataContext` of your `ContentDialog` to the selected item to enable binding on its properties.

```
private async void DisplayCommentDialog_v3(Approvals rowModel)
{
    MgmtApprovalDialog.DataContext = rowModel;
    ContentDialogResult result = await MgmtApprovalDialog.ShowAsync();
```

Then, assuming `Approvals` has a `string Comment` property, you can use the following binding on your `TextBox`.

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding Comment}" (...) />
```

### Solution 2: Subclass ContentDialog

If you don't want to use bindings, you can also create a class derived from `ContentDialog` which allows you to add custom logic and expose extra members.
You can find an example of this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3).

In your case it could look like the following.

```cs
public sealed partial class ApprovalDialog: ContentDialog
{
    public ApprovalDialog()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();        
    }

    public void SetComment(string comment)
    {
        Cmnt_Apprvl_Mgmt.Text = comment;
    }
}
```

Then you would call the extra method before showing the dialog:

```cs
private async void DisplayCommentDialog_v3(Approvals rowModel)
{
    // Again, I don't know if `Comment` is the correct property name.
    MgmtApprovalDialog.SetComment(rowModel.Comment);
    ContentDialogResult result = await MgmtApprovalDialog.ShowAsync();
```

You would also need to change your xaml to include `x:Class` to specify your custom type.

```xml
<ContentDialog x:Class="YourNameSpace.ApprovalDialog"
               x:Name="MgmtApprovalDialog"
               Title = "Enter Management Approval Comment"
      (...)
```

Comment: Thank you Batesias, I implemented solution #1 and it worked!  I don't totally understand solution #2 yet, but I will try a stub program to test it out. .... I think I am beginning to understand solution #2 more and more, the more I look at it.  Thank you again!  I really appreciate your help.